# I can everything

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Is this ever grammatically possible - "**I can everything**"?

I have just read this on a jacket one girl is wearing.

P.s. I think it's **made in china**.

Comment: Atleast we know that these manufacturers '_can_' (do) anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it is not standard grammar.

Whether it is intentional or not is unanswerable. It could be a deliberate bending of the "rules" for effect. It could be representing the kind of "mistake" that someone makes when they are over-excited.

Of course standard English would have "I can do everything". But this doesn't give the effect of excitement.